# Hide patterns when unlocking protected apps?

Tags: cyanogenmod, micromax-yu-yureka

[image: Protected App Pattern]
<sub>(source: [virtualthoughts.org](http://virtualthoughts.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/cyanogenmod-protected-apps-2.png))</sub>

Is there any way to hide pattern in **Protected Apps** App in CM11 ?